# Fastest pythonic way to loop over dictionary to create new Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary "c" with 30000 keys and around 600000 **unique** values (around 20 **unique** values per key)

I want to create a new pandas series "'DOC_PORTL_ID'" to get a sample value from each row of column "'image_keys'" and then look for its key in my dictionary and return.  So I wrote a function like this:

```
def find_match(row, c):
    for key, val in c.items():
        for item in val:
            if item == row['image_keys']:
                return key
```

and then I use .apply to create my new column like:

```
df_image_keys['DOC_PORTL_ID'] = df_image_keys.apply(lambda x: find_match(x, c), axis =1)
```

This takes a long time.  I am wondering if I can improve my snippet code to make it faster.

I googled a lot and was not able to find the best way of doing this.  Any help would appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You're using your dictionary as a reverse lookup.  And frankly, you haven't given us enough information about the dictionary.  Are the 600,000 values unique?  If not, you're only returning the first one you find.  Is that expected?

---

#### Assume they are unique

```
reverse_dict = {val: key for key, values in c.items() for val in values}

df_image_keys['DOC_PORTL_ID'] = df_image_keys['image_keys'].map(reverse_dict)
```

---

This is as good as you've done yourself.  If those values are not unique, you'll have to provide a better explanation of what you expect to happen.

Comment: If the values are list, will this still work given that lists are not hashable

Comment: At which point are the values lists?  `{'key0': ['v0', 'v1', 'v2'], 'key1': ['v3', 'v4', 'v5']}`?  For this it will work.  If not, then you have done a poor job explaining yourself and have wasted both of our time.

Comment: Yeah exactly, like if dict[key0] = ['v0', 'v1', 'v2']

Comment: Then it should work.  Why haven't you tried it?  Instead of asking if it works... check to see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  They are unique, I will edit my question